# Using LINQ with Lucene for querying an index with live projection

Tags: linq, lucene.net, ravendb

I have defined an index with the following syntax:

```
public class TestCasesForConfigurationModeIndex 
      : AbstractIndexCreationTask<TestCase>
{
     TestCasesForConfigurationModeIndex() 
     {
         Map = docs => from x in docs select new { x.CurrentName }
         Indexes.Add(x => x.CurrentName, FieldIndexing.Analyzed); 
         TransformResults = ... select new TestCaseForConfigurationMode { ... }
     }
}
```

Querying this index via the Raven Studio works as expected, but how can I perform the same query using the LINQ API? The problem is that the "As" extension method is not availble for IDocumentQuery, but only for 
var query = _db.Advanced.LuceneQuery()
.As().ToArray();

I also tried something like the following:

```
var results = _db.Advanced.LuceneQuery<TestCase, TestCasesForConfigurationModeIndex>()
     .WhereEquals(x => x.CurrentName, searchExpression).Fuzzy((decimal)0.5);
     .AsQueryable().As<TestCaseForConfigurationMode>().ToArray();
```

This kind of works (the server console shows me "Results: 7 returned out of 7 total." which is correct), but I don't get any results back (empty array).

Answer (score 3):

You can use [SelectFields<>](http://ravendb.net/docs/2.5/client-api/querying/results-transformation/select-fields), for example:

```
Session.Advanced.LuceneQuery<IndexModel, Index>()
    .Where("Name:(Bill) ...")
    .SetResultTransformer("MyResultTransformer")
    .SelectFields<MyResultTransformer.Result>()
    .ToList();
```

Make sure to have Result Tranformers (MyResultTranformer in this example) in [separate class](http://ravendb.net/docs/2.5/client-api/querying/results-transformation/result-transformers)

Answer (score 0):

You might need to use:

```
 using Raven.Client.Linq;
```

to import the As extension method.

Comment: The As extension method is valid for objects of type IQueryable, but the lucene query is of type IDocumentQuery<T> which does not implement IQueryable. I now use the following dirty workaround, but hopefully there is a better solution available out-of-the-box: 

var serializer = JsonExtensions.CreateDefaultJsonSerializer();
var results = query.QueryResult.Results.Select(x =>
  serializer.Deserialize(new RavenJTokenReader(x), 
  typeof(TestCaseForConfigurationMode)))
).ToArray();

Answer (score -1):

Try using `.OfType<T>()` instead of `.As<T>()`.  They are synonyms for the same functionality.

Also, you don't necessarily need to transform results in order to use it (depending on what you're doing).